# No qualifying bean of type [com.app.fetcher.DataFetcher] found for dependency

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I know there are similar questions, but I've tried multiple solutions and none of them worked.

I have a DataFetcher class

```
package com.app.fetcher;

@Component
public class DataFetcher{

    private ArrayList<Data> data = new ArrayList<>()        

    public DataFetcher() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadData(){
        //load data from external API and store it to data collection
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

and a simple controller to handle requests

```
package com.app.controller;    

@Controller
public class DataController {

    @Autowired
    private DataFetcher dataFetcher;

    @RequestMapping("/data")
    public String showData(Model model){

        model.addAttribute("data",dataFetcher.getData());

        return "showData";
    }
}
```

my beans.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan
            base-package="com.app">
    </context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

My classes are located in `src/main/java` and my beans.xml in `src/main/resources`

When I deploy this app to tomcat8, during deployment (and when trying to access the site) it throws this exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.app.fetcher.DataFetcher] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:997)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:867)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:779)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:490) 
//another 20 entries from spring
```

Any idea how to fix this? I've tried wiring the beans by hand and still get the same error.

EDIT: as requested, my web.xml (location: is in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`)

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>showData</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>showData</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and full DataFetcher class

```
package com.app.fetcher;


import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Component
public class DataFetcher {
    private final static String SERVER_STATUS_QUERY = "/api/wow/realm/status";

    private ArrayList<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public DataFetcher() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://eu.battle.net" + SERVER_STATUS_QUERY);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            String input;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(input);
            }

            in.close();
            parseData(stringBuilder.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void parseData(String json) {
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);

            JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("realms");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                data.add(new Data(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"), jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("type")));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Data> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<Data> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to move the beans.xml to src/main/resources/WEB-INF

Comment: Didn't help. Tried moving beans.xml to various other places but I'm still getting the same exception when deploying and accessing the page.

Comment: How do you configure your webapp? Can you show us your web.xml ?

Comment: I don't think this issue is due to the location of beans.xml file because Spring is able to recognize @Autowired annotation in `DataController.java`. Could you please add complete DataFetcher.java?

Comment: @R4J added web.xml to OP and also added complete DataFetcher. It polls Blizzard's servers for WoW realm status and stores realm name and realm type. I'm using http://www.json.org/java/ to parse JSON